# Как открыть меню контактов через Telegram Web App, чтобы получить их chat id?

Tags: typescript, telegram

Пишу telegram web app на typescript, хочу получать список контактов чтобы потом получать их chatid. Например есть бот @wallet в нем это выглядит так:

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]
[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Чтобы вызвать это меню, нужно в эту ссылку

```
https://t.me/имя бота?startattach=send&choose=users
```

добавить имя своего бота, но доступна эта опция только для рекламодателей телеграма